# VBA Visio aligning object to the middle

Tags: vba, visio

I have problems with assigning the 2 or more vision objects to the middle.

My chart looks like this

[image]

and I want to have all of them aligned in one line.

The code I have looks as follows:

```
Dim VPage As Page
Set VPage = ActiveDocument.Pages("SLD")

Dim Vshp As Visio.Shape
Dim sel As Visio.Selection
Set sel = ActiveWindow.Selection
For Each Vshp In VPage.Shapes
If Vshp.Name Like "*UG*" Then
 sel.Select Vshp, visSelect
 sel.Selection.Align visHorzAlignNone, visVertAlignMiddle, False
 End If
 Next
```

At the following line:

```
  sel.Selection.Align visHorzAlignNone, visVertAlignMiddle, False
```

The error: **Object doesn't support this property or method**  is displayed

I am wondering what is wring here, as I've picked up these codes from recorded macro and it was working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the help documentation for the [Selection.Align method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.align), you will see the following words

> Aligns two or more selected shapes.

For first selected shape this method can get error!

I don't understand what you want to do ?
Iterate all the connectors and align them vertically in the middle?
In this case, all connectors vertically (except the first of the selected ones) can change their position. Unless they are glued to the connection points on the green squares.
[image: moved]

If they are glued, they won't move anywhere. In other words, nothing will happen.
[image: not moved]

---

Please modify code of Align method to `sel.Align visHorzAlignNone, visVertAlignMiddle, False`.

You can also put this line outside the loop to align all shapes once

```
Dim Vshp As Visio.Shape
Dim sel As Visio.Selection
Set sel = ActiveWindow.Selection
For Each Vshp In VPage.Shapes
If Vshp.Name Like "*UG*" Then
 sel.Select Vshp, visSelect
 End If
 Next
sel.Align visHorzAlignNone, visVertAlignMiddle, False
```

Comment: I would like to align them horizontally as displayed in my image.

Comment: I modify my answer, there i fix syntax of line with **Selection.Align method**.